# Narrowing scopes of quantifiers in Z3

Tags: z3

There is a `distribute-forall` tactic that can be used for distributing universal quantifiers over conjunction.  I'm interested in a more general procedure for both universal and existential quantifiers that would narrow the scope of quantifiers as much as possible. 
For example, I'd want the formula

`(exists ((x Int)) (and (= z (* 2 x)) (<= z y)))` be transformed into

`(and (exists ((x Int)) (= z (* 2 x)) (<= z y)))`.

Can this be done via some other tactic(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branch `mcsat` in the Z3 code base has a new tactic called `miniscope`. It does what you want. We can build the `mcsat` branch using [these instructions](https://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation). We just have to replace `unstable` with `mcsat`.

Here are some examples using this tactic.

```
(declare-const z Int)
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)

(assert (exists ((x Int)) (and (= z (* 2 x)) (<= z y))))

(apply miniscope)
```

and the produced output

```
(goals
(goal
  (<= z y)
  (exists ((x!1 Int)) (= z (* 2 x!1)))
  :precision precise :depth 3)
)
```

Here is a more complicated example:

```
(set-option :pp.max-depth 100)
(declare-fun p (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun q1 (Int Real) Bool)
(declare-fun q2 (Real Real) Bool)
(declare-fun q3 (Int Int) Bool)

(assert (forall ((x1 Int) (x2 Real))
                (or (q2 x2 x2) (exists ((y Real)) (and (q1 y x2) (q1 x1 x2))))))

(apply miniscope)
```

and the produced output

```
(goals
(goal
  (forall ((x2 Real))
    (or (q2 x2 x2)
        (and (forall ((x1 Int)) (q1 x1 x2))
             (exists ((y Real)) (q1 (to_int y) x2)))))
  :precision precise :depth 3)
)
```

**EDIT**

The `mcsat` branch contains work-in-progress that will be eventually merged into the `master` branch. However, the merge will probably not occur in the next official release (v4.3.2). When we release a new version, we merge `unstable` and `contrib` branches into the `master` branch.

The `mcsat` branch is essentially adding new functionality. It is not incompatible with the `unstable` and `contrib` branches.

We encourage advanced users (familiar with git) to use non-official releases and alternative branches. Of course, when reporting bugs/problems, the git hash associated with the commit should be used instead of the version number.

**END EDIT**

Comment: Thank you. Is "miniscope" tactic a branch-specific one? I mean, do you think one can "integrate" it with the source code of the master branch with relatively low efforts? I'm just unaware of how the mcsat branch  differs from the master, so I don't know what switching to that branch may also affect. Do you plan adding that tactic in the main branch eventually?

Comment: I expanded the answer with additional information regarding the `mcsat` branch.